# Find max value for a key of a hash of a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Trying to figure out a way to get the max/min values out of a hash of hash. Example would be that I want to get the player with the highest deaths and the player with the highest kills.

Example of a hash:

```
{ 1234 => 
     { :steamID => 1234,
       :alias => "Bob",
       :kills => "50",
       :deaths => "10"
     },
  5678 => 
     { :steamID => 5678,
       :alias => "Jim",
       :kills => "10",
       :deaths => "12"
     },
}
```

Trying to get an output of something like:

```
{ :most_kills => 
    { :steamID => 12345, 
      :name => "Bob", 
      :stat => "50"}, 
  :most_deaths => 
    { :steamID => 12345, 
      :name => "Bob", 
      :stat => "50"
    }
 }
```

Comment: It is entirely not clear what leads you to the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will find the player with the max *kills* and *deaths* stats and map the output to the desired format:

```
input = { 1234 =>
  { steamID: 1234,
    alias: "Bob",
    kills: "50",
    deaths: "10"
  },
  5678 =>
   { steamID: 5678,
     alias: "Jim",
     kills: "10",
     deaths: "12"
   },
}

output = [:kills, :deaths].each_with_object({}) do |stat, h|
  max = input.max_by {|k,v| v[stat]}

  h["most_#{stat}".to_sym] = {
    :steamID => max[0],
    :name => max[1][:alias],
    :stat => max[1][stat]
  }
end
```

The output is:

```
{
  :most_kills => {
    :steamID => 1234, 
    :name => "Bob", 
    :stat => "50"
  }, 
  :most_deaths => {
    :steamID => 5678,
    :name => "Jim", 
    :stat => "12"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a minor mistake tho...
Need to change:
`:stat => max[1][:kills]`

To:
`:stat => max[1]["#{stat}".to_sym]`

Answer (score 0):

I might write it like this:

```
def most(input, key_name)
  _, v = input.max_by { |_,v| v[key_name.to_sym] }
 [("most_#{key_name}").to_sym, v]
end

["deaths", "kills"].map {|key_name| most(input, key_name) }.to_h
   #=> {:most_deaths=>{:steamID=>5678, :alias=>"Jim",
   #                   :kills=>"10", :deaths=>"12"},
   #    :most_kills =>{:steamID=>1234, :alias=>"Bob",
   #                   :kills=>"50", :deaths=>"10"}}
```